# Blazor Server: OnInitialized Method Triggered Twice Causing Animation to Render Twice

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a Blazor Server application and I've noticed an issue where the OnInitialized method is being hit twice - once during prerendering and again after the connection has been established in the browser. This is causing a static HTML razor component that has an animation done in CSS to animate twice.

Here's a simplified example of my component:

```
@page "/example"

<h3>@title</h3>

@code {
    private string title;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        title = "Page is initialized";
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized is called");
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

In this example, "OnInitialized is called" is printed twice in the console, and the title "Page is initialized" is set twice. This is a simplified example, but in my actual application, I have a CSS animation that is triggered during initialization, and this animation is also happening twice.

I understand that Blazor Server operates in a way that it initializes components during prerendering and again after establishing a connection. But is there a way to prevent this double initialization, or at least a way to detect whether the initialization is happening during prerendering or after connection so I can control the animation accordingly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the render-mode from *ServerPrerendered* to *Server*  in `_Host.cshtml`:

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering